# How to write a custom debugging helper for nlohmann::basic_json?

Tags: python, c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I am faced with the task of writing a simple debug helper for Qt Creator 4.13.1 / Qt 5.12.5 / MSVC 2017 compiler for the C++ JSON implementation `nlohmann::basic_json` (https://github.com/nlohmann/json).

An object of `nlohmann::basic_json` can contain the contents of a single JSON data type (*null*, *boolean*, *number*, *string*, *array*, *object*) at a time.
There's a `dump()` member function which can be used to output the current content formatted as a `std::string` regardless of the current data type. I always want to use this function.

What I've done so far:

- I've looked at https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging-helpers.html, as well as at the given example files (*qttypes.py*, *stdtypes.py*...).
- I made a copy of the file *personaltypes.py* and told Qt Creator about its existence at
  *Tools* / *Options* / *Debugger* / *Locals & Expressions* / *Extra Debugging Helpers*

The following code works and displays a "Hello World" in the debugger window for `nlohmann::basic_json` objects.

```python
import dumper

def qdump__nlohmann__basic_json(d, value): 
    d.putNumChild(0)
    d.putValue("Hello World")
```

Unfortunately, despite the documentation, I have no idea how to proceed from here on.
I still have absolutely **no** clue how to correctly call `basic_json`'s `dump()` function with the dumper from Python (e.g. with `d.putCallItem` ?).

I also have no starting point how to format the returned `std::string` so that it is finally displayed in the debugger window.

I imagined something like this, but it doesn't work.

```python
d.putValue("data")
d.putNumChild(1)
d.putCallItem('dump', '@std::string', value, 'dump')
```

I hope someone can give me a little clue so that I can continue thinking in the right direction.
For example, can I call `qdump__std__string` from *stdtypes.py* myself to interpret the `std::string`?